# My bubble sort is introducing values of '0' in array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I used a 'bubble-sort' for my C++ program, but it introduces random '0' values in array in a Fractional Greedy Program

```
int sorteaza()
{
    int aux,schimb,i;
    do
    {
        schimb=0;
        for (i=0;i<=n;++i)
            if (G[i][3]<G[i+1][3])
            {
            swap(G[i], G[i+1]);
            }
    }
    while (schimb);
}
```

This is my entire code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int n; // Numarul de elemente
float G[100][3]; // Obiecte + detalii masa profit potenta
int masa = 0;

int read_data()
{
cout << "Greutatea Rucsac" << endl;
cin >> masa;
cout << "Obiecte: " << endl;
cin >> n;
for(int i = 1; i<=n;i++)
{
    for(int j = 1; j<=2;j++)
    {
        cin >> G[i][j];
        if(G[i][1] != 0 && G[i][2] != 0)
        {
         G[i][3] = G[i][2] / G[i][1];
        }

    }
}
}
// 2 500
// 4 500

int sorteaza()
{
    int aux,schimb,i;
    do
    {
        schimb=0;
        for (i=0;i<=n;++i)
            if (G[i][3]<G[i+1][3])
            {
            swap(G[i], G[i+1]);
            }
    }
    while (schimb);
}
int verify()
{
for(int i = 1; i<=n;i++)
{
    for(int j = 1; j<=3;j++)
    {
        cout << G[i][j];
        cout << endl;
        //G[i][3] = G[i][1] / G[i][2];
    }
}
}

int greedy()
{

    float profit = 0;
    int i = 1;
    int aux;
    while(i<=n && masa>=0)
    {
        //cout << "G[i][1]: " << G[i][1] << endl;
        if(masa>=G[i][1]) {
        //cout << "Am ajuns aici";
        profit=profit+G[i][2];
        masa=masa-G[i][1];
        }
        else {
                        //cout << "Am ajuns dincolo";
                aux= (masa*100)/G[i][1];
                profit = profit + (aux * G[i][2])/100;
                break;
                        }
    i++;
   }
cout << profit;
    }










int main()
{
    read_data();
    sorteaza();
    verify();
   // greedy();

}
```

Comment: Did you debug to find out what's happening?

Comment: Yes, but useless..

Comment: If `G[i]` is an array of three elements, then what is the top index of `G[i]`?

Comment: The top of G[i] is n.

Comment: Debugging is useless?! This will never end up on a t-shirt.

Comment: Furthermore, are you sure that `i + 1` will be a valid index of `G` itself? And I don't see you initialize `G[0]`. To summarize, take a closer look at *all* your array indexes.

Comment: No, the top of `G[i]` is ***`2`***. And yet you use `G[i][3]`.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/163/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn to index all your arrays from zero.

```
float G[100][3];
```

Legal indexes are 0 to 99 and 0 to 2. So this code should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        cin >> G[i][j];
    }
    if (G[i][0] != 0 && G[i][1] != 0)
    {
        G[i][2] = G[i][1] / G[i][0];
    }
}
```

and this code should be

```
        if (G[i][2] < G[i+1][2])
        {
            swap(G[i], G[i+1]);
        }
```

All your arrays start at zero. I'm sure you've been told this, but you have to start putting it into practise.

In general, write your for loops like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
```

That's the correct loop for an array of size `N`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need `<n` instead of `≤n` (that's where the uninitialized value i.e. 0 comes from). And you miss one loop in the bubble sort. Right now you're only bubbling the smallest element to the end of the list.

Also no idea what you're doing with that `schimb` and while condition.

Furthermore you're defining G as `float[100][3]` so you can't use `G[i][3]`, only `G[i][2]`.

```
int sorteaza()
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        {
            if (G[i][2] < G[j][2])
            {
                swap(G[i], G[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```